# css3pie not working for all elements

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css3pie

I'm getting strange problem with pie.htc and IE8. I have many elements on page that has rounded corners but pie works only for one element. My CSS is correct - I mean selectors are correctly assigned to pie behavior.
What elese could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some experience using css3 pie and they have not been great. Here are the fixes i have used:

- The elements that you are applying the behavior library too need to be **position: relative** for a start, so check that first. It may fix it.
- If you want it to work in IE6 and 7 you need to add **zoom: 1**. I know you said you were using IE8 but my customers have said that in the past and it has been in compatibility mode, so always best to add that setting.
- CSS 3 Pie does not support browser zooming either on background images so check that you are viewing the website in the 100% view and no other.

Hope that has helped. If you could post a jsfiddle then I could try and help further. If not check the css3pie known issues http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Problem was that for these elements was used background with filter. Also css3pie sets background for these elements. After removing this filter everything works fine.